# JPA - Insert many tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to know if theres somehow to insert multiples tables at one-time.

Example:

```
Class A {...}
Class B {...}
Class C {A a, B b}

C.setA(new A());
C.setB(new B());
```

Then, when I try to insert the object C, it doesn't let me because JPA says that doesn't exists any a or b object in Database. So, I have to insert A, then B, then C. One by one, which is really bad to go to the Database 3 times everytime that I want to insert 3 new objects.

Theres somehow to JPA interpret that I want to insert the class C and their dependencies (A and B)?

Thanks!

Comment: you may need Cascade.persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this we can use the JPA cascading functionality:

```
@Entity
Class C {
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private B b;
}
```

With this, by calling persist in a C, you will also persist it's A and B at the same time.

Comment: What if I want to insert C that has an existing A and B in DB? It will recognize if I set the existing ID to A and B?

Comment: you need to use merge and not persist, which only for new objects. as long as the A and B have their Id fields (meaning database keys) correctly filled in, it should work OK

Comment: You sure? If I want to insert a new C and use an existing A and B, then using merge will work fine? I thought merge worked like UPDATE.